# How Drupal identifies "Display on user registration form." in from array

Tags: forms, theming

How Drupal identifies "Display on user registration form." in from array
[image]

**I want to do something with the "Display on user registration form." by `form_alter`**

may be hide it or whatever.

```
[field_first_name] => Array
        (
            [#type] => container
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => field-type-text
                            [1] => field-name-field-first-name
                            [2] => field-widget-text-textfield
                        )

                )

            [#weight] => 3
            [#tree] => 1
            [#language] => und
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [#entity_type] => user
                            [#entity] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [uid] => 0
                                    [hostname] => 111.92.58.145
                                    [roles] => Array
                                        (
                                            [1] => anonymous user
                                        )

                                    [cache] => 0
                                )

                            [#bundle] => user
                            [#field_name] => field_first_name
                            [#language] => und
                            [#field_parents] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [#columns] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => value
                                    [1] => format
                                )

                            [#title] => Full Name
                            [#description] => 
                            [#required] => 1
                            [#delta] => 0
                            [#weight] => 0
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [#entity_type] => user
                                    [#entity] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [uid] => 0
                                            [hostname] => 111.92.58.145
                                            [roles] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [1] => anonymous user
                                                )

                                            [cache] => 0
                                        )

                                    [#bundle] => user
                                    [#field_name] => field_first_name
                                    [#language] => und
                                    [#field_parents] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [#columns] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => value
                                            [1] => format
                                        )

                                    [#title] => Full Name
                                    [#description] => 
                                    [#required] => 1
                                    [#delta] => 0
                                    [#weight] => 0
                                    [#type] => textfield
                                    [#default_value] => 
                                    [#size] => 60
                                    [#maxlength] => 255
                                    [#attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [class] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => text-full
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [#input] => 1
                                    [#autocomplete_path] => 
                                    [#process] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => ajax_process_form
                                        )

                                    [#theme] => textfield
                                    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => form_element
                                        )

                                    [#pre_render] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => ctools_dependent_pre_render
                                        )

                                    [#defaults_loaded] => 1
                                    [#tree] => 1
                                    [#parents] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => field_first_name
                                            [1] => und
                                            [2] => 0
                                            [3] => value
                                        )

                                    [#array_parents] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => field_first_name
                                            [1] => und
                                            [2] => 0
                                            [3] => value
                                        )

                                    [#processed] => 1
                                    [#title_display] => before
                                    [#id] => edit-field-first-name-und-0-value
                                    [#name] => field_first_name[und][0][value]
                                    [#value] => 
                                    [#ajax_processed] => 
                                    [#sorted] => 1
                                )

                            [#tree] => 1
                            [#parents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => field_first_name
                                    [1] => und
                                    [2] => 0
                                )

                            [#array_parents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => field_first_name
                                    [1] => und
                                    [2] => 0
                                )

                            [#processed] => 
                            [#attributes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [#title_display] => before
                            [#id] => edit-field-first-name-und-0
                        )

                    [#theme] => field_multiple_value_form
                    [#field_name] => field_first_name
                    [#cardinality] => 1
                    [#title] => Full Name
                    [#required] => 1
                    [#description] => 
                    [#prefix] =>
<div id="field-first-name-add-more-wrapper">
                    [#suffix] =></div>
                    [#max_delta] => 0
                    [#after_build] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => field_form_element_after_build
                        )

                    [#language] => und
                    [#field_parents] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#tree] => 1
                    [#parents] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => field_first_name
                            [1] => und
                        )

                    [#array_parents] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => field_first_name
                            [1] => und
                        )

                    [#weight] => 0
                    [#processed] => 
                    [#attributes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#title_display] => before
                    [#id] => edit-field-first-name-und
                    [#after_build_done] => 1
                )

            [#access] => 1
            [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => container
                )

            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_process_container
                )

            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_first_name
                )

            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => field_first_name
                )

            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#title_display] => before
            [#id] => edit-field-first-name
            [#sorted] => 1
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox is added from [user_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_alter/7), which checks the settings for the instance being edited.

```
  $instance = $form['#instance'];

  if ($instance['entity_type'] == 'user') {
    $form['instance']['settings']['user_register_form'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Display on user registration form.'),
      '#description' => t("This is compulsory for 'required' fields."),
      // Field instances created in D7 beta releases before the setting was
      // introduced might be set as 'required' and 'not shown on user_register
      // form'. We make sure the checkbox comes as 'checked' for those.
      '#default_value' => $instance['settings']['user_register_form'] || $instance['required'],
      // Display just below the 'required' checkbox.
      '#weight' => $form['instance']['required']['#weight'] + .1,
      // Disabled when the 'required' checkbox is checked.
      '#states' => array(
        'enabled' => array('input[name="instance[required]"]' => array('checked' => FALSE)),
      ),
      // Checked when the 'required' checkbox is checked. This is done through
      // a custom behavior, since the #states system would also synchronize on
      // uncheck.
      '#attached' => array(
        'js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'user') . '/user.js'),
      ),
    );
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'user_form_field_ui_field_edit_form_submit');
  }
```

It is [user_field_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_field_info_alter/7) that adds the setting property to the fields.

Comment: How can i use this in my module ?

Comment: You didn't say what you want to achieve with your module.